# One component of border implies simply-connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Is it right that any open connected *bounded* subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one connectedness component (in usual or linear sense) of border is simply-connected?

For me it seems to be kind of Jordan curve theorem, though I do not know how to derive it.

Comment: You mean the boundary of $U$ is connected?

Comment: Thank you, I mistaken my English.

Comment: That wouldn't be bounded @DanielFischer

Comment: Somehow, that word didn't make it through my spectacles, @Stefan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Alexander duality,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) since the reduced homology of the boundary is trivial, so is the first homology of its complement (and in two dimensions that implies that the domains are simply connected).

Comment: A minor remark: You should work with the Chech cohomology of the boundary (since it need not be path-connected). However, Alexander-Poincare duality work for Chech cohomology as well.

Comment: @studiosus true enough